# Is there anyway I can update my app after it was killed using a push-notification? (Firebase - iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I'm planning a new feature for a school related app. This new feature would send a notification showing the next period the student has. However, sometimes there are special schedules and the times for the notifications need to be changed. In addition all student information must stay on the device. Is there any way I can update the notification times (using firebase) when the app is killed (manually force-quit)?

I would prefer to use silent notifications but if needed, I can send a visible push notification to update the notification times.

Comment: Have you checked Firebase Remote Config. You can update specific variable for your app using Firebase Console.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, remote config works but only when the app is running in the foreground. I want to make this change without needing the user to launch the app (i.e. killed). I understand how to make the schedule update when the app is in the foreground / background, but the hard part is updating it when it's killed.

Comment: If the user has killed the app then a push notification won't wake it. The best you can do is send a regular push that asks the user to open the app (which they can do by tapping the notification)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will do that.